# Node mssql transaction causing select query to wait

Tags: sql-server, node-mssql

I am using Node `mssql` to connect to a SQL Server database from my node application. Inside the application, I have logic to loop through more than 1000 rows and call different procedures based on output of each procedure. All this logic is inside a transaction.

Once all 1000 rows have been processed successfully, I commit the transaction. In case of failure, I rollback the transaction.

For each procedure call, I am creating new `Request` object:

```
const myrequest = new sql.Request(mytransactionConnection);
```

I am facing two problems:

1. It takes 15 seconds to complete the transaction for 1000 rows
2. While the transaction is in progress and if I run a `select` query in Management Studio on any of the tables involved in `UPDATE` or `INSERT` during the transaction, the `SELECT` query just waiting for transaction to get completed

Any suggestion to handle above two problems?

Comment: SQL is very slow at procedural logic. Looping through records and calling an SP for each will be slow. I suggest you rework your logic to work on groups of records. Tables being blocked while another transaction is modifying is the standard behaviour.

Comment: An `INSERT` or `UPDATE` will ultimately hold an **exclusive** lock on one or more rows in the tables involved, and this x-lock will only be released when the transaction ends (with commit or rollback). You cannot change that. You can either use `WITH (READPAST)` on your `SELECT` to skip any locked rows, or you can just leave it as is and wait for the transaction to complete, or you'd have to investigate other transaction isolation levels, like snapshot isolation levels, to get around this.